why won't pass allow entries to be added or edited?
I have been using pass (cli pw manager) for a couple of years now, and I just started using yubikeys.
I have (2) YKs which I configured as duplicates of each other, transferring the same gpg subkeys (S, E, and A) to each one.
I added the YK gpg-key id to my ~/.password-store/.gpg-id file, and re-initialized the store to re-encrypt the entries using the new key.
I can now use pass with either of my YKs to open a password-store entry using pass, however, when I try either to edit an existing entry or to add a new one, I am met with:
$pass add test
Enter password for test: 
Retype password for test: 
gpg: B7C0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1BB7: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
Password encryption aborted.

A check on the key returns:
$gpg -K YUBI
sec#  rsa4096/289xxxxxxxxxx8B5 2024-11-01 [SC] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Key fingerprint = 8C6B xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx 58B5
      Keygrip = E7608xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx37AFD
uid                 [ultimate] Fname Lname (YUBIKEY) <user@protonmail.com>
ssb>  rsa4096/130xxxxxxxxxxA7D 2024-11-01 [S] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Keygrip = 18DD9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1599B
ssb>  rsa4096/A39xxxxxxxxxxEBD 2024-11-01 [E] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Keygrip = 5BD06xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8B9FD
ssb>  rsa4096/779xxxxxxxxxxBAA 2024-11-01 [A] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Keygrip = 0A10BxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAFA2F

and
gpg -k YUBI
pub   rsa4096/289xxxxxxxxxx8B5 2024-11-01 [SC] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Key fingerprint = 8C6B xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx 58B5
      Keygrip = E7608xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx37AFD
uid                 [ultimate] Fname Lname (YUBIKEY) <user@protonmail.com>
ssb>  rsa4096/130xxxxxxxxxxA7D 2024-11-01 [S] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Keygrip = 18DD9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1599B
ssb>  rsa4096/A39xxxxxxxxxxEBD 2024-11-01 [E] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Keygrip = 5BD06xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8B9FD
ssb>  rsa4096/779xxxxxxxxxxBAA 2024-11-01 [A] [expires: 2034-10-30]
      Keygrip = 0A10BxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAFA2F

Trying to re-import the pub made no changes, as expected.
Encrypting a file like:
$ gpg -r YUBIKEY -e file
then decrypting it with:
$ gpg -d file.gpg
works as expected. I am prompted for the passphrase and file contents are listed afterward.
Now I am confused and unsure what the issue is. If anyone has any suggs or advice I would sure appreciate it. Thks.

Ok, the issue ended up being that there were still old key IDs listed in the password-store .gpg-id file, which must have been trippeing pass up, because when they were removed and the gpg-agent restarted, everything just started working as expected, including editing and adding new entries.
